# sap.m.PlanningCalendar: How to hide or skip weekends

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sapui5

I was wondering if it would be possible for an sap.ui.unified.CalendarAppointment in a sap.m.CalendarRow to skip the weekends. This would mean that the appointment would be separated into two blocks. Any idea how to start with this? I can't seem to find anything about this topic.

If this is not possible, would the best idea be hiding the weekends with CSS?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zT3tH.png)

Thanks for your input.

Greetings

Matthijs

Comment: Show us one calendar in action please.

Comment: I added a screenshot. As you can see, the appointments also extend in the weekend. Any tips?

Comment: i beed the actual thing to find a solution :). Go do a fidfle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably make a new type of appointment which would span a number of weekends and underneath it would create a number of sap.ui.unified.CalendarAppointment instances to make it look like separate appointments skipping weekends.

Otherwise you have to redefine and tweak a CalendarRowRenderer and it looks less easy. The Appointment itself is rendered in function **CalendarRowRenderer.renderAppointment** and it is not an element or control, it's a rectangle with absolute position, so you have to thoroughly calculate all the sizes to tweak it via CSS.